# Why does bash use unintuitive operators for text and numeric conditional expressions?

Tags: bash, operators, posix, language-design

Something that has been bothering me for years - why does bash use unintuitive operators for text and numeric conditional expressions? Is there some historic or technical reason behind this, is it enforced by a standard that is followed (e.g. POSIX) or is it simply down to the preferred style of the language authors?

For example, when performing string comparisons in bash:

```
[[ "X" == "X" ]]
[[ "X" != "Y" ]]
```

we use operators that appear to have a background in logic or mathematics. However, when comparing numbers, we use operators that are not mathematical or logical:

```
[[ 2 -eq 2 ]]
[[ 2 -lt 3 ]]
```

Just to clarify - the answer I am looking for here is why was the language designed this way, i'm not asking about how comparisons work in bash (there are already plenty of questions and answers on this).

Answer (score 3):

Actually in BASH you can use `((...))` and use all standard operators like:

```
((2==2))
((2<3))
((i>=5))
```

For more details check **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION** in `man bash`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however the question I am asking is why was the language designed this way, rather than looking for details around how comparisons work. I will update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: There are historical reasons behind it. BASH scripts need be backward compatible with old POSIX `sh` as well.